# Load a 3d model in webgl

Tags: json, webgl, three.js

I have a 3DS file that I want to load in webgl. I can convert it into an OBJ, JSON or JS file type. I tried it with and without using THREE.js. I just can't figure it out, can anyone walk me through how to make this model show up?

Comment: What part are having troubles with? What have you tried? How is it not working? You could start by getting some of the example files running( three.js/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html ), then replacing the example model with your own file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the current THREE.js, and the current version of Autodesk's FBX converter, try [Verold's FBX->JSON Converter for Three.js](http://verold.com/blog/2012/11/27/designing-the-fbx-converter-for-threejs), which is part of the github repository for THREE. This appears to be the best, most-complete way to get data from Max/Maya to THREE so far.

Comment: Thanks, however my issue is mainly getting the converted model loaded and visible in webgl

Comment: then try it. getting your max model into webgl is exactly it's function :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work to get an OBJ into the scene, though you will want to add a merterial at some point. I am working with max for my current project and exporting from max to OBJ and then loading into three.js is working fine.

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.addEventListener('load', objLoaded);
objLoader.load(filepath);

function objLoaded (event) {
    scene.add(event.content);
}
```